# How to put two figures in the same page?

Tags: floats

[image]

I am trying to put two figures in the same page of my paper, but although there is still enough space for the second figure in the first page, the second picture won't appear in the first page. Anybody can help?

```
Meanwhile, we also generate figures about the distribution of debris based on size (\textbf{Figure 5}, \textbf{Figure 6}). 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{1cm-10cm.png}
    \centering
    \caption{Spatial density of space debris ranging from 1cm to 10cm.}
\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{10cm.png}
    \centering
    \caption{Spatial density of space debris larger than 10cm.} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you try setting `\textfraction` (default is `0.2`) to a lower value, say 0.1 or 0.05?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some notes:

- To solve your issue, to each figure add `\begin{figure}[!htb]`
- Only one `\centering` is enough inside a figure/table environment, so you can remove the second one in each.
- The "Figure 5 and Figure 6" you manually added can be done automatically by Latex, by adding `\label{<your label>}` inside of each figure then writing `\ref{<your label>}` or `\cref{<your label>}` (with the `cleveref` package) in the text. The label is of course, arbitrary.

---

`cleveref` offers some ways to customize your labels. For example

- `\cref{} = fig.`
- `\Cref{} = Fig.`

If you want to make all of them capitalized, then add `capitalise` to the package options. With a couple of additional commands we can make all of that bold, but I strongly suggest you don't use this because it will be too highlighted compared to the text.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{\textbf{#2#1#3}}
\crefname{figure}{\textbf{Fig.}}{\textbf{Figures}} 

\begin{document}  
Meanwhile, we also generate figures about the distribution of debris based on size (\cref{top}, \cref{bottom}). 
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Spatial density of space debris ranging from 1cm to 10cm.}
    \label{top}
\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Spatial density of space debris larger than 10cm.} 
    \label{bottom}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Vinnton No problem! I thought of using `\subfigure` but that would make the automatic reference write `fig. 1a` and `fig. 1b` (instead of 1 and 2) which I thought was not your intention.

Comment: Yes I have tried `\subfigure` but that's not what I want. And now I have a new problem: I have tried your method of `\cref{}` but it will generate lower case citation, while I wish to get upper class and bold citation  (like **Fig.1** rather than fig.1). Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @Vinnton Yes, but the bold is not really advisable because all your references will stand out.

Comment: But I found quite a lot of papers using bold citation~

Answer (score 9):

If you want the figures to be on the same page no matter what, use a single `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Meanwhile, we also generate figures about the distribution of debris based
on size (figures \ref{top}~and~\ref{bottom}).

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Spatial density of space debris ranging from 1cm to 10cm.}\label{top}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Spatial density of space debris larger than 10cm.}\label{bottom}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Remember the `p` position specifier.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would this method change the sizes of figures? It seems that figure B is a little bit distorted.

Comment: @Vinnton I used `height=5cm` in order to fit both figures in the current page. That's the reason why they're distorted.