# How do I put two figure environments above text and under text on the same page?

Tags: floats

This latex code spans across two pages but I want to have it on one page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[right = 12mm, left=12mm, top=0.5in, bottom=5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 y = ac + b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 y = mc + c
\end{equation}

\section{text}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{ONE.jpg}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\section{text}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{TWO.jpg}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: A picture of the images on two pages]

Comment: For another similar issue (but caused by a different reason `\textfraction`), see  [floats - How to put two figures in the same page? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290186/how-to-put-two-figures-in-the-same-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There simply is not room to fit images of that size in to the area you have specified. I made them smaller and they fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[right = 12mm, left=12mm, top=0.5in, bottom=5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}


\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
 y = ac + b\\
 y = mc + c
\end{gather}

\section{text}


\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3.7cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\section{text}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3.7cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David for showing that the container of figure must be able to fit onto the page too, if it doesn't then the image moves onto the next page.

Answer (score 1):

If any one comes across this problem, you can also change the

```
\usepackage[right = 12mm, left=12mm, top=0.5in, bottom=5in]{geometry}
```

to

```
\usepackage[right = 12mm, left=12mm, top=0.5in]{geometry}
```

removing

```
bottom=5in
```

this will give you more space on the page to add stuff