# Placing two figures one above the other and allow them along with their captions to fit on the same page. Ideally the figures will fit the entire page

Tags: graphics, formatting, captions, page

Is there a way to make the two figures that I have included in my document to be placed on the same page

So far I see the following:

[image]

The code I have written so far is this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{W.png}
    \caption{ ksd fxk sdkjf nksdzkulvskjzvlkzxsdlvsdlj. sdflkjznscfv dlk jnvl dfzlvxjkcnlk vndflkj. jnskjlnsdljkfn klkjsndflkjnsddlfk fsklj fklsjdnz flkjzskl sdlkj fnzsdkjlfnlksjznf lkjsdznfjkndflzxkj nlky}
    \label{fig:W}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{U.png}
    \caption{ksd fxk sdkjf nksdzkulvskjzvlkzxsdlvsdlj. sdflkjznscfv dlk jnvl dfzlvxjkcnlk vndflkj. jnskjlnsdljkfn klkjsndflkjnsddlfk fsklj fklsjdnz flkjzskl sdlkj fnzsdkjlfnlksjznf lkjsdznfjkndflzxkj nlky \cite{halle1981ionization}. }
    \label{fig:U}
\end{figure}
```

I put nonsense in the captions because I will edit it later.

Ideally I would like to force overleaf to place the two figures on one page and the two figures combined with their captions should fill the entire page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible way is to put inages into \vbox and type inside of box: \makeatletter\def\@captype{table}

Comment: Remove the lines 6 to 9 (`\end{figure} \begin{figure} \centering` ),  but probably you must also reduce the size of the images.

Comment: Is there a way that latex can adjust the shapes automatically so that both image sizes are adjusted so that they both fit fully inside the page along with their captions?

Comment: Instead of defining the width, you can define the height of the images.

Comment: I could mention that two [p] floats can use 100% of a page whereas [t] can only use about 70% (\topfraction) or a [t] and a [b] for 80% (\textfraction), but your floats are too big either way.

Comment: See also (for the *fraction issues mentioned above) [floats - How to put two figures in the same page? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290186/how-to-put-two-figures-in-the-same-page)

Answer (score 1):

This scales both images to the same width so as to fit them into the available space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{ ksd fxk sdkjf nksdzkulvskjzvlkzxsdlvsdlj. sdflkjznscfv dlk jnvl dfzlvxjkcnlk vndflkj. jnskjlnsdljkfn klkjsndflkjnsddlfk fsklj fklsjdnz flkjzskl sdlkj fnzsdkjlfnlksjznf lkjsdznfjkndflzxkj nlky}\label{fig:W}}% labels should go inside saveboxes (local \@currentlabel)
    \setbox1=\vbox{\caption{ksd fxk sdkjf nksdzkulvskjzvlkzxsdlvsdlj. sdflkjznscfv dlk jnvl dfzlvxjkcnlk vndflkj. jnskjlnsdljkfn klkjsndflkjnsddlfk fsklj fklsjdnz flkjzskl sdlkj fnzsdkjlfnlksjznf lkjsdznfjkndflzxkj nlky \cite{halle1981ionization}. }\label{fig:U}}%
    \setbox2=\vbox{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
    \edef\temp{\the\dimexpr \textheight-\floatsep-\ht0-\dp0-\ht1-\dp1}% available height
    \ifdim \ht2<\temp 
      \def\scale{1.0}%
    \else
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{\temp/\ht2}% cannot use \dimen0
    \fi
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \scale\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \unvbox0
    \vskip\floatsep
    \includegraphics[width = \scale\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \unvbox1
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]